# Stripe "trial_period_days" Not working PHP

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a subscription using stripe API.
But it wont save once i included the ***"trial_period_days_" => $trial_days*** to the code.

***$trial_days*** contains an integer which subtracts the days left on the present month and adds 14 days. This is executing perfectly if you echo it out it will show the number.

```
     $trial_days = (date("m", strtotime("-1 months"))+14);
```

Here is my code.

```
        $stripe_subscription =   \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
            "customer" => $stripe_customer->id,
            "items" => array(
                "plan" => $stripe_plan->id,
                "trial_period_days" => $trial_days
            )
        ));
```

Here is the API JSON Map

```
"items": {
"object": "list",
"data": [
  {
    "id": "si_DPjpkyc3UVZfuI",
    "object": "subscription_item",
    "created": 1534221712,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "plan": {
      "id": "plan_DPjnUAy2jqHSkS",
      "object": "plan",
      "active": true,
      "aggregate_usage": null,
      "amount": 5000,
      "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
      "created": 1534221598,
      "currency": "aud",
      "interval": "month",
      "interval_count": 1,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "nickname": "FPA",
      "product": "prod_DPjmRCMbpYGdgJ",
      "tiers": null,
      "tiers_mode": null,
      "transform_usage": null,
      "trial_period_days": null,
      "usage_type": "licensed"
    },
```

Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: What is in your $trial_days variable? Log it to see, because you make the call.

Comment: Edited, Thanks for pointing it out.
it contains an integer.

Comment: _"it wont save"_ <- what does this mean, exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: The stripe API specifies you need an array of arrays: \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => "cus_BypGKKdoZVdpFo",
  "items" => array(
    array(
      "plan" => "8",
    ),
  )
)); Whereas you just have items as an array with fields in it directly; items should be an array containing another array, then with the items in it?

Comment: Also; are you sure trial_period_days belongs in the items array; according to the API it looks to be outside the items array, at the same level as it?

Answer (score 1):

You have `trial_period_days` under `items` when it should be at the same level as `items`, like so:

```
    $stripe_subscription =   \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
        "customer" => $stripe_customer->id,
        "items" => array(
            "plan" => $stripe_plan->id
        ),
        "trial_period_days" => $trial_days
    ));
```

That ought to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use something like this

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
    'customer' => 'cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
    'items' => [['plan' => 'plan_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f']],
    'trial_end' => 1536048827,
]);
```

It will work. I am using this in my current Org.